# What does this mean in regular expressions? re.match(r"(^[cf-qs-z]+)", any file name)?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pattern-matching, match

I stumbled upon this code and I do not know what does it match:

```
re.match(r"(^[cf-qs-z]+)", words)
```

Comment: If you stumbled upon code and don't know what it means, the best source to ask is whoever wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `f-q` and `s-z` are *character ranges*, meaning any letter from `f` to `q` and from `s` to `z` in the alphabet, case sensitive
- `c` is a *literal character* `c` - no special meaning
- `^` defines the *beginning of a string*
- `+` is a *quantifier*, it means "one or more"
- parenthesis define a *capturing group*

In other words the expression would match 1 more characters that are `c` or in `f` to `q` or `s` to `z` range at the start of a string.

In cases like this, if you need an explanation for an existing regular expression, try pasting it to https://regex101.com, here is what it generates for this expression: https://regex101.com/r/cU0yT7/1.